# Swapping vector to free it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion, vector

I've read that the best way to free the memory of a vector is:

```
vector<int>().swap(my_vector);
```

And i don't really understand what is happening.The swap function takes 2 vectors and swaps their elements, so for instance:

```
vector<int>v1{1,2,3};
vector<int>v2{4,5,6};
v1.swap(v2);
```

v1 becomes {4,5,6} and v2 becomes {1,2,3}.This looks normal. But how does my first example free the memory? What happens inside the memory? If my_vector swaps elements with vector () (an empty vector), then doesn't the empty vector get my_vector elements, and my_vector becomes empty?

Comment: it does not free memory. Swap change the memory addres of the first v1's element from v1 to v2

Comment: Ohh, so this is how swapping works? I thought that it is done with some for loops:)). Then, how can i free the memory?

Comment: Because you swap memory with a temporary empty vector instance that gets instantly destroyed after `;`

Comment: To free it, call `vector::clear`, and then `vector::shrink_to_fit`. Or simply let the vector go out of scope. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I've read that the shrinktofit method is not good

Comment: Usually you let the vector do it's thing and you don't tell him how to do them. If you really absolutely need to free the memory, probably because your program is close to taking all available memory, you would, however. Again, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I am new to vectors so i'm still learning

Comment: Also, as for your post, if you created a temporary vector and do the swap there, then yeah, your old vector would be as if it was just initialized, which comes down somewhat similar to what I wrote. However, note that there are no specifications on the initial capacity of a vector - that new constructed vector could theoretically have any capacity it wants, and then your old one would have that after the swap. (Will be zero in most real cases, though.)

Answer (score 2):

You're not only swapping with an empty vector, you're swapping with a *temporary* empty vector. So the memory of the two vectors is swapped, and then the destructor of the temporary vector frees the memory which originally was `my_vector`s.

Note that the standard effectively guarantees that in this case `swap` is swapping the allocated memory. Otherwise, this method could raise an exception, which it is [forbidden to do in this case](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/). Also, note that the default constructor of `vector` is also exception-free, so it effectively cannot allocate memory. As Aziuth correctly notes in the comment, it could theoretically have a small capacity non-dynamic initial buffer, and this would be transferred in the swap. In practice, this is probably negligible.

Comment: I didn't know you can declare a vector temporarly.. I am new to vectors, i ve been using only arrays.

Comment: @HeroForFun The way you wrote it, `vector<int>()`, makes it a temporary.

Comment: @HeroForFun Why did you believe you couldn't declare a temporary vector?  You can declare practically anything as temporary in C++.

Comment: I'd add to your answer that this temporary empty vector is not guaranteed to have any specific capacity. Will have zero in pretty much every real case, but theoretically, it would be allowed to have any.

Comment: @Aziuth Good point, thanks! Added also a note on the exception guarantee of the default constructor as long with your point.